# Unable to post using AngularJS & PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, json, api

I'm running an AngularJS [app](http://e-citywheels.com/new/appAdmin2/).

I've ran in locally before and I could post to the local server.

Now I'm trying it on the live server and I get the following error:

```
Unable to create Reservation.
```

This error is posted from the `create.php` page, whenever it's unable to post to the server.

Anyone know what's wrong with my code?

**create.php page**

```
  <?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate reservation object
include_once '../objects/reserve.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$reservation = new Reservation($db);

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set product property values
$reservation->name = $data->name;
$reservation->eMail = $data->eMail;
$reservation->phoneNumber = $data->phoneNumber;
$reservation->colorScooter = $data->colorScooter;
$reservation->amountScooters = $data->amountScooters;
$reservation->inputDate = $data->inputDate;
$reservation->returnDate = $data->returnDate;
$reservation->category_id = $data->category_id;
$reservation->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// create the reservation
if($reservation->create()){
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Reservation was created."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to create the reservation, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Unable to create Reservation."';
    echo '}';
}
?>
```

**EDIT 02-08-18**

It seems it's not setting the property values.

```
    // set product property values
$reservation->name = $data->name;
$reservation->eMail = $data->eMail;
$reservation->phoneNumber = $data->phoneNumber;
$reservation->colorScooter = $data->colorScooter;
$reservation->amountScooters = $data->amountScooters;
$reservation->inputDate = $data->inputDate;
$reservation->returnDate = $data->returnDate;
$reservation->category_id = $data->category_id;
$reservation->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I can see this when running the opening the `create.php` live vs locally

**locally**

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>30</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api2\reserve\update.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />
{"message": "Unable to update reservation."}
```

**Live**

```
 {"message": "Unable to update reservation."}
```

It seems on live it's not looking for the property values

Running on HP 7.0 (7.0.28)

added:

`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

and now got the following displayed

```
Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/128/313118/webspace/httpdocs/e-citywheels.com/new/api2/reserve/create.php on line 32
```

**EDIT ADDED RESERVE.PHP**

```
<?php
class Reservation{

    // database connection and table name
    private $conn;
    private $table_name = "reservations";

    // object properties
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $eMail;
    public $phoneNumber;
    public $colorScooter;
    public $amountScooters;
    public $inputDate;
    public $returnDate;
    public $category_name;
    public $created;

    // constructor with $db as database connection
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    // read reservations
    function read(){

        // select all query
        $query = "SELECT
                    c.name as category_name, p.id, p.name, p.eMail, p.phoneNumber,  p.colorScooter, p.amountScooters, p.inputDate, p.returnDate, p.category_id, p.created
                FROM
                    " . $this->table_name . " p
                    LEFT JOIN
                        categories c
                            ON p.category_id = c.id
                ORDER BY
                    p.created DESC";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
    // create product
    function create(){

        // query to insert record
        $query = "INSERT INTO
                    " . $this->table_name . "
                SET
                    name=:name, eMail=:eMail, phoneNumber=:phoneNumber, colorScooter=:colorScooter, amountScooters=:amountScooters, inputDate=:inputDate, returnDate=:returnDate,category_id=:category_id, created=:created";

        // prepare query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
        $this->eMail=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->eMail));
        $this->phoneNumber=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->phoneNumber));
        $this->colorScooter=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->colorScooter));
        $this->amountScooters=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->amountScooters));
        $this->inputDate=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->inputDate));
        $this->inputDate=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->returnDate));
        $this->category_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->category_id));
        $this->created=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->created));

        // bind values
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":eMail", $this->eMail);
        $stmt->bindParam(":phoneNumber", $this->phoneNumber);
        $stmt->bindParam(":colorScooter", $this->colorScooter);
        $stmt->bindParam(":amountScooters", $this->amountScooters);
        $stmt->bindParam(":inputDate", $this->inputDate);
        $stmt->bindParam(":returnDate", $this->returnDate);
        $stmt->bindParam(":category_id", $this->category_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(":created", $this->created);

        // execute query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
    // used when filling up the update product form
    function readOne(){

        // query to read single record
        $query = "SELECT
                    c.name as category_name,  p.id, p.name, p.eMail, p.phoneNumber,  p.colorScooter, p.amountScooters, p.inputDate, p.returnDate, p.category_id, p.created
                FROM
                    " . $this->table_name . " p
                    LEFT JOIN
                        categories c
                            ON p.category_id = c.id
                WHERE
                    p.id = ?
                LIMIT
                    0,1";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

        // bind id of product to be updated
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        // get retrieved row
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // set values to object properties
        $this->name = $row['name'];
        $this->eMail = $row['eMail'];
        $this->phoneNumber = $row['phoneNumber'];
        $this->colorScooter = $row['colorScooter'];
        $this->amountScooters = $row['amountScooters'];
        $this->inputDate = $row['inputDate'];
        $this->returnDate = $row['returnDate'];
        $this->category_id = $row['category_id'];
        $this->category_name = $row['category_name'];
    }

    // update the product
    function update(){

        // update query
        $query = "UPDATE
                    " . $this->table_name . "
                SET
                    name = :name,
                    eMail = :eMail,
                    phoneNumber = :phoneNumber,
                    colorScooter = :colorScooter
                    amountScooters = :amountScooters,
                    inputDate = :inputDate,
                    returnDate = :returnDate,
                    category_id = :category_id
                WHERE
                    id = :id";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
        $this->eMail=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->eMail));
        $this->phoneNumber=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->phoneNumber));
        $this->colorScooter=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->colorScooter));
        $this->amountScooters=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->amountScooters));
        $this->inputDate=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->inputDate));
        $this->inputDate=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->returnDate));
        $this->category_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->category_id));
        $this->id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));





        // bind new values
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":eMail", $this->eMail);
        $stmt->bindParam(":phoneNumber", $this->phoneNumber);
        $stmt->bindParam(":colorScooter", $this->colorScooter);
        $stmt->bindParam(":amountScooters", $this->amountScooters);
        $stmt->bindParam(":inputDate", $this->inputDate);
        $stmt->bindParam(":returnDate", $this->returnDate);
        $stmt->bindParam(':category_id', $this->category_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);

        // execute the query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // delete the product
    function delete(){

        // delete query
        $query = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table_name . " WHERE id = ?";

        // prepare query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $this->id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));

        // bind id of record to delete
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);

        // execute query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    // search products
    function search($keywords){

        // select all query
        $query = "SELECT
                    c.name as category_name, p.id, p.name, p.eMail, p.phoneNumber,  p.colorScooter, p.amountScooters, p.inputDate, p.returnDate, p.category_id, p.created
                FROM
                    " . $this->table_name . " p
                    LEFT JOIN
                        categories c
                            ON p.category_id = c.id
                WHERE
                    p.name LIKE ? OR p.description LIKE ? OR c.name LIKE ?
                ORDER BY
                    p.created DESC";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $keywords=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($keywords));
        $keywords = "%{$keywords}%";

        // bind
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $keywords);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $keywords);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $keywords);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }

    // read products with pagination
    public function readPaging($from_record_num, $records_per_page){

        // select query
        $query = "SELECT
                    c.name as category_name, p.id, p.name, p.eMail, p.phoneNumber,  p.colorScooter, p.amountScooters, p.inputDate, p.returnDate, p.category_id, p.created
                FROM
                    " . $this->table_name . " p
                    LEFT JOIN
                        categories c
                            ON p.category_id = c.id
                ORDER BY p.created DESC
                LIMIT ?, ?";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );

        // bind variable values
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $from_record_num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $records_per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        // return values from database
        return $stmt;
    }

    // used for paging products
    public function count(){
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_rows FROM " . $this->table_name . "";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $row['total_rows'];
    }

}
```

**Added 11-08-2018**

Adding `var_dump($product);` results in showing that the variable `$product` does return the table and `$data` is actually where to problem lies.

result of `var_dump($product);`

```
 ["table_name":"Product":private]=>
  string(8) "products"
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  NULL
  ["email"]=>
  NULL
  ["phone"]=>
  NULL
  ["amount"]=>
  NULL
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["pickup"]=>
  NULL
  ["back"]=>
  NULL
  ["category_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["category_name"]=>
  NULL
  ["created"]=>
  NULL
```

> Current status

If I open the create.php file it does create a product, but If i use the form I get the error Unable to create product.

Also when I open the create.php file I get the following error message:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api\product\create.php</b> on line <b>37</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api\product\create.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api\product\create.php</b> on line <b>39</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api\product\create.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api\product\create.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api\product\create.php</b> on line <b>42</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api\product\create.php</b> on line <b>43</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\api\product\create.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
```

It seems it can't find the "name" properties.

I've got the idea whats causing the issue,

**factory**

```
// create product
factory.createProduct = function($scope){
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            'name' : $scope.name,
            'email' : $scope.email,
            'phone' : $scope.phone,
            'amount' : $scope.amount,
            'description' : $scope.description,
            'pickup' : $scope.pickup,
            'back' : $scope.back,
            'category_id' : 1
        },
        url: 'http://localhost/api/product/create.php'

    });
};
```

**my controller**

```
// create new product
$scope.createProduct = function(){

    productsFactory.createProduct($scope).then(function successCallback(response){

        // tell the user new product was created
        $scope.showToast(response.data.message);

        // refresh the list
        $scope.readProducts();

        // close dialog
        $scope.cancel();

        // remove form values
        $scope.clearProductForm();

    }, function errorCallback(response){
        $scope.showToast("Unable to create record.");
    });
}
```

**product.php**

```
    // create product
function create(){

    // query to insert record
    // $query = "INSERT INTO " . $this->table_name . 
    // "(name, email, phone, amount, description, pickup, back, created, modified)" .
    // " VALUES(:name, :email, :phone, :amount, :description, :pickup, :back, :created, :modified)";

    $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                name=:name, email=:email, phone=:phone, amount=:amount, description=:description, pickup=:pickup, back=:back, category_id=:category_id, created=:created";

    // prepare query
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    // sanitize
    $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->email=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));
    $this->phone=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->phone));
    $this->amount=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->amount));
    $this->description=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->description));
    $this->pickup=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->pickup));
    $this->back=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->back));
    $this->category_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->category_id));
    $this->created=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->created));

    // bind values
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $this->email);
    $stmt->bindParam(":phone", $this->phone);
    $stmt->bindParam(":amount", $this->amount);
    $stmt->bindParam(":description", $this->description);
    $stmt->bindParam(":pickup", $this->pickup);
    $stmt->bindParam(":back", $this->back);
    $stmt->bindParam(":category_id", $this->category_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(":created", $this->created);

    // execute query
    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

**Create.php**

```
<?php


// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate product object
include_once '../objects/product.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$product = new Product($db);

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

echo $data;

var_dump($data);

var_dump($product);


print_r($data);

var_dump($product->name);

// set product property values
$product->name = $data->name;
$product->email = $data->email;
$product->phone = $data->phone;
$product->amount = $data->amount;
$product->description = $data->description;
$product->pickup = $data->pickup;
$product->back = $data->back;
$product->category_id = $data->category_id;
$product->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');



var_dump($product->name);
var_dump($data->name);

echo is_array($product->name) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';

echo json_last_error();
// create the product
if($product->create()){
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Product was created."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to create the product, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Unable to create product."';

    echo '}';
}


?>
```

**Update 08-12-2018**

Running the createproduct() it does `post` it into `create.php`

I checked it with google chrome's inspector network tab.

```
{name: "test", email: "test", phone: "test", amount: "test", description: "test", pickup: "test",…}
amount
:
"test"
back
:
"test"
description
:
"test"
email
:
"test"
name
:
"test"
phone
:
"test"
pickup
:
"test"
```

it also returns code:200

which according to this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340) means:

200 OK
This response code indicates that the request was successful.

201 Created
This indicates the request was successful and a resource was created. It is used to confirm success of a PUT or POST request.

It seems it's not creating new resources and nothing has been posted.

Comment: Are you getting the same error even when all the params are sent?

Comment: Yes, If I enter all params I get the error, please take a look I've hyperlinked my app at the top.

Comment: error only at `$reservation->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` line eh? Can you post reserve.php too?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil I've added it! No It seems it doesn't call any of the properties

Comment: Unable to recreate the problem.Your code is working for me . have you tried printing `$data`?

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil Thanks for your effort, `print($data)` does nothing. Have you tried creating a product on my app using my hyperlink in the top?

Comment: Yes. I did. Throws me the same error. If data is null . then there must be something wrong with json . have you tried `echo json_last_error()`?

Comment: No, I'm quite new with JSON and angular, do I add this to the create.php file?

Comment: adding the line to `create.php` file results in this: `4<font color=ff0000>
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/128/313118/webspace/httpdocs/e-citywheels.com/new/api2/reserve/create.php on line 33
</font>{"message": "Unable to create Reservation."}` I think it's not requesting the properties for some reason, weird.

Comment: So,  4=> there is a error in your json . [json_last_error](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) returns last known error. Try printing data before decoding it `echo file_get_contents("php://input");` in your create.php

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil Running `echo file_get_contents("php://input");` does nothing, look: http://e-citywheels.com/new/api2/reserve/create.php

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil ` echo file_get_contents("php://input");

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` It's like this now

Comment: Are you still getting the same errors? I tried posting data it echo's `{"name":"test","eMail":"test","phoneNumber":123,"colorScooter":"red","amountScooters":2,"inputDate":21,"returnDate":22,"category_id":1} {"message": "Unable to create Reservation."}`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why its not able to create the post. data in echo's?

Comment: yes . So data is the set properly.

Comment: ` $this->table_name`  - I'm not seeing anywhere that you define it in class `Reservation`.  So if you `json_decode()` your input json string, do you get what you expect wtih `print_r($decoded_string)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you use php://input? Is there a reason why you are not using $_POST to access the posted data? If a POST-Request hits php the global associative array $_POST gets created. Each index will match one of your name-attributes from your form and contain its value.

The errors displayed could come from this approach because php://input can be anything, so $data can be. If that's the case you try to assign values ($reservation->name = $data->name;) out of an object which is actually not an object.

```
// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set product property values
$reservation->name = $data->name;
$reservation->eMail = $data->eMail;
$reservation->phoneNumber = $data->phoneNumber;
$reservation->colorScooter = $data->colorScooter;
$reservation->amountScooters = $data->amountScooters;
$reservation->inputDate = $data->inputDate;
$reservation->returnDate = $data->returnDate;
$reservation->category_id = $data->category_id;
$reservation->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

clarify the datatype of $data and make sure it stays the same no matter what. (try using var_dump instead of echo or print_r, grants additional information)

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, whats the best way to ensure that each $data is on actual object.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I should use the $_POST ?

Comment: give all your form-fields a name-attribute and hit your entrypoint with a post-request followed by a var_dump($_POST); you will see its an associative array with indexes matching your name-attributes so for example if you have an input like this <input type="text" name="username"> you can access the posted data with echo $_POST["username"];  edit: to save some work with your already coded structure you could just map the $_POST array to an object matching your already existing structure.

Comment: where do I place the `$_POST` ? In the `create.php`?

Comment: yes in create.php above your „// get posted data“ print_r($_POST); followed by an exit(); to stop further execution

Answer (score 1):

make sure to check all variable values and array values before doing any transaction. You can validate them at any point you want by using

```
isset()
```

and

```
is_array()
```

So, you will get clear idea about whic one is not set at the right place. So you will be able to trace it very clearly. Otherwise you will waste your time by tracing the problem.

Comment: Will try it out, weird part is I've build this app based on a tutorial. I've repeated the steps and sometimes it worked and sometimes it did not.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check what you get on `file_get_contents("php://input")` (var_dump)
2. In factory.createProduct you have `url: 'http://localhost/api/product/create.php'`. Is this what you want? Calling from remote to localhost? Souldn't you use `'/api/product/create.php'`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Using the url `http://localhost/api/product/create.php` or `/api/product/create.php` doesn't make a difference. I've tried to `var_dump it and it returns` `string(0) ""
`